# Where on the orbit of 101955 Bennu would an impact deflection mission have the most chance of success

Tags: angular-momentum, orbital-motion, asteroids

Asteroid Bennu has a *slight* change of impact with Earth in the year 2135 (or 2182) and thus is a prime candidate for a future deflection mission using an impact spacecraft.

Given that the orbit of Bennu is near the earth's orbit and moves inside and outside of it, I was wondering where along the orbit would such a mission give us the greatest chance of success.

[image: fig1]

Possible locations are:

1. Near the predicted intersection point
2. On the opposite location from the intersection point
3. Where it is further from the Earth's orbit on the inside, and has the highest momentum.
4. Where it is further from the Earth's orbit on the outside, and has the lowest momentum.

Orbital mechanics are weird, but knowing that Bennu would return to the point of impact in the future, I can safely exclude #1 from the list above (unless two impact missions are planned).

Comment: Just a thought. I wonder if it would be possible to deflect it so that it hit the moon.

Comment: Interesting article - [Asteroid Bennu: The squishy space rock that almost swallowed a spacecraft](https://www.space.com/39958-asteroid-bennu.html)